# MS Acess loop, adding x to checkbox

Tags: ms-access, vba

Need some help looping thru check boxes in access. I have three checkboxes, checkbox1, checkbox2, checkbox3.
x = 1
I can't get the syntax to loop with "check" & x or checkx or check(x)
Is there a way to declare the checkbox name with the number variable x?

Thanks!

```
Private Sub Refer_Click()
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As String

x = 1
y = ""

Do Until x = 4
    If Checkx = True Then
      y = y & Checkx.Controls(0).Caption & ";"
      x = x + 1
    Else: 
      x = x + 1
      y = "unchecked"
End If
Loop

fillThis.Value = y


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have 10 checkboxes on a form, each named like "chk" plus a sequential number, you can use the following:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    Debug.Print Me.Controls("chk" & i).Name & vbTab & Me.Controls("chk" & i).Value
Next i
```

Comment: Do Until x = 4
        If Me.Controls("check" & x) = True Then
        y = y & Me.Controls("check" & x).Controls(0).Caption & "; "
        x = x + 1
        Else: x = x + 1
        End If
        Loop